# Ignore JSON field Play Controller Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a situation where I have an incoming data model as

```
case class Person(name: String,
                  age: Int,
                  contact: Int)
```

But, I want to ignore the **name** property as I would not be receiving it but I need it to persist it in DB which I am injecting in later.

One option could be to make it optional but in that case I need to create another model for DB which is kind of redundant.

Could anybody provide a solution with JSONCombinator READ to avoid reading the field at all?

Thanks

Comment: Either make it an option (not recommanded), either create your custom reader with and ignore the field to default it to empty string (not recommanded), either create another case class `PersonCreation` which only contains 2 fields (best approach)

Comment: Cheers @Louis F. .. thanks for your reply... Yes it seems 2 classes would be easy and good but do you have any example how "I could ignore the field and default it to empty String". Again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom `Reads` and default the name to empty string :

```
  import play.api.libs.json._ // JSON library
  import play.api.libs.json.Reads._ // Custom validation helpers
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._ // Combinator syntax

  implicit val customReads: Reads[Person] = (
    (JsPath \ "age").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "contact").read[Int]
  )((age, contact) => Person(name = "", age = age, contact = contact))
```

**Edit**

```
  implicit val customWrites: Writes[Person] = (
    (JsPath \ "age").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "contact").write[Int]
  )((person) => (p.age, p.contact))
```

Comment: Thanks again @Louis F. ... And how would I write the customWrite ignoring the name.. I know it sounds very dumb but I am very new to all this and kind of can't figure it out..

Comment: Thanks again for such a quick reply... you are awesome!